# Element Updates in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm just starting out with Angular and figured I'd be best off to jump right into angular 2.

What I've read in several places leads me to believe that Angular "magically" updates the dom when a component's model changes. The following quote is from http://victorsavkin.com/post/118372404541/the-core-concepts-of-angular-2 (updated Jan 4, so should be current).

> Host Element
>
> To turn an Angular component into something rendered in the DOM you have to associate an Angular component with a DOM element. We call such elements host elements.
>
> A component can interact with its host DOM element in the following ways: * It can listen to its events. * It can update its properties. * It can invoke methods on it.
>
> The component, for instance, listens to the input event using hostListeners, trims the value, and then stores it in a field. Angular will sync up the stored value with the DOM.
>
> [removed code]
>
> Note, I don’t actually interact with the DOM directly. Angular 2 aims to provide a higher-level API, so the native platform, the DOM, will just reflect the state of the Angular application.

So, my code:

```
(function(app) {
  app.topMenu =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'top-menu',
      template: '<span>{{time}}</span>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() { 
        this.time = 'Never Changes';

        setInterval(function () {
          var listeners = document.getElementsByClassName('time');
          var currentTime = new Date(Date.now());
          var options = { 
            hour12: 'true',
            weekday: 'long',
            month: 'long',
            day: 'numeric',
            year: 'numeric'
          }

          this.time = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-us',options);
          console.log(this.time);
        }, 1000);
      }
    });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.topMenu);
  })
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

The problem is that the DOM never updates after the initial page load, while the console ticks along happily. What do I need to add to make the DOM update its content to the model's changes?

Comment: If the code isn't the "angular way" I'd be happy for pointers. This is day 2 of Angular for me, and I'm trying to stick to JS rather than TypeScript for now.

Comment: Speaking of the "angular way", I'm also getting my feet wet with angular 2 and think it's worth doing it in Typescript. A lot of of the messiness goes away. Also niceties like the `=>` operator save a lot of grief by making `this` beahve in an easier way when you have callbacks. In your example, check that `this.time` in your `setInterval` callback is what you think it is.

Comment: It's not the Angular2 way. They are really pushing TypeScript for this reason because I have been using Angular2 with TypeScript and your code looks foreign right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZoneJS is responsible to trigger the change detection of Angular2 (that updates the view accordingly). This means that you need to have the corresponding JS file (`angular2-polyfills.js`) included into your HTML page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    (...)
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    (...)
  </head>
  (...)
</html>
```

That's why you can use directly the `setTimeout` function and Angular2 doesn't provide a `timeout` service.

Moreover I see a bug in your code. You should use an arrow function to be able to use the `this` keyword corresponding to the component

```
setInterval(() => {
  (...)
  this.time = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-us',options);
}, 1000);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: You're right, the `=>` fixed the problem. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Yes only included the file i's enough for zones. So your problem should be the use of "this" in the setTimeout function. Using the arrow function (my second remark) should fix your problem ;-)

Comment: "ZoneJS is responsible to detect under the hood that attributes of your component changed and update the view accordingly."  I don't think ZoneJS does all that.  ZoneJS creates an execution context and monkey patches the browser async calls.  When an async event fires, after your callback handler runs, Zonejs calls Angular's change detection. Angular's change detection checks for changes to component input properties and propagates changes, and it checks template bindings, and it updates the DOM with any changes it found.    At least... I think that's how it all works.

Comment: Yes, agreed with you, Mark! I just wanted to tell that ZoneJS needs to be there to trigger change detection but I didn't want to enter in more details. Perhaps it wasn't so clear. I updated the first sentence of my answer in this way. Thanks very much for your comment ;-)